# Unable to Save a File (Created by WSL & Ubuntu) on VSCode using "ctrl + S"

Tags: c, visual-studio, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cs50

As I was trying to save a file called `parity.c` (created thorugh coding `code parity.c`), an error occurred that said `wsl+Ubuntu` needs to be updated to `security.allowedUNCHosts` by which I already did.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GZQL.png)

However, as I tried to save it again using "ctrl + S", another error occurred. This time it is the "UNKNOWN ERROR".

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu8Ee.png)

How to explain this error and how to solve it besides saving it manually through `Save As`?

Comment: It looks like you are running Visual Studio directly in Windows, but are saving the file through the WSL file system - but target the normal Windows domain. What if you just replace ```\\wsl+Ubuntu\mnt\c\``` with ```C:\``` ? I can't access my `C` drive via the WSL mount from Windows either, but from within WSL there's no problem.

Comment: I wonder how to replace it with "C:\"? Sorry, I'm just a beginner. @Ted Lyngmo

Comment: Open the file via ```C:\...``` (not ```\\wsl+Ubuntu\mnt\c\```) - when you save it, it _should_ then save it using the same path.

Comment: So, you mean  `wsl+Ubuntu` can create a file by coding it but cannot save the file created by the terminal right? :) @Ted Lyngmo

Comment: I'm unsure exactly what you mean. As I said at first, it looks like you are running Visual Studio in Windows but for some reason try to save a file through wsl even though the target path is in your own Windows ```C:\Users\...``` directory. How do you open the file in Visual Studio?

Comment: @Jason - We are saying that you access the file system in an unusual way. It is known that Ubuntu can mount and read Windows disks, but are reluctant to write files, because the Windows file system is closed source and not publicly documented in detail. Perhaps this is what happens here?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Well, I opened the file using the Windows file system but I created it using WSL.

Comment: Does the project file perhaps contain wsl-paths? I don't know much about VS Code but I guess that would be one possibility.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Yeah, it has.

Comment: Unless you really need those for something else, you could perhaps just change all of them to point directly to your windows path. You won't be able to work with it from within wsl afterwards though so I guess You'll have to decide if you'd like to work with with the project in Windows or WSL.

Comment: @JasonTee, Have you tried opening the vs code from the wsl itself?, if not just open your wsl and then type "code ." to open the currect project folder in vs code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.